# TCP client for Android: text is not received in full

Tags: android, tcp

I am converting a Java desktop project to Android. Part of it includes a TCP connection to a server and parsing a long text from the server to the client (the Android application). This is the code that I have for the desktop project that I also try to use in Android:

```
// Method is called when a button is tapped
public void tapButton() {

    // Create a message to the server that requests for the Departure navdata
    String messageToServer = someMethodToMakeHandshakeMessage();

    // Connect to the server
    if (!messageToServer.equals("")) {
        String finalMessageToServer = messageToServer;

        new Thread(() -> {
            String navdata = connectClient(finalMessageToServer);

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> messageReceived(navdata));
            // I am also using messageReceived(navdata) without runOnUiThread with the same result
        }).start();
    }
}

public String connectClient(String messageOut) {

    Socket socket = null;
    DataInputStream input = null;
    DataOutputStream output = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    // Final message from the server
    String data = "";
    // Message from the server that should terminate TCP connection
    String  terminator = "END_DATA";

    try {
        // Create socket and streams
        socket = new Socket(someIPAddress, somePort);
        input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        //Send message to the server
        output.writeBytes(messageOut);
        //Read Response
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s = "";
        int value = 0;

        // Process the message from the server and add to the StringBuilder
        while((value = br.read()) != -1) {
            // converts int to character
            char c = (char)value;

            sb.append(c);

            if(sb.toString().contains(terminator)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Create the final string
        data = sb.toString();
    }

    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // Dealing with exception
    }

    catch (EOFException e) {
        // Dealing with exception
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        // Dealing with exception
    }

    finally {
        try {
            if(socket!=null) { socket.close();}
            if(input != null) { input.close();}
            if(output != null) { output.close();}
            if(br != null) { br.close();}
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            // Dealing with exception
        }
        socket = null;
        input = null;
        output = null;
        br = null;
    }

    return data;
}

public void messageReceived(String message) {
    // Method to deal with received data
}
```

Whereas the code works fine in the desktop Java application, I have problems with Android (using an emulator). The text is not sent in full length and is cut somewhere in the middle (only 20-50% received by the client; the number of parsed characters differs all the time). Besides, I have noticed that it is taking too long to connect to the server, but, I guess, this is due to working with an emulator.

Should a TCP client receiving long texts from the server be implemented in Android somewhat differently?

EDIT: Implemented the following code using a suggestion by @blackapps:

```
String line = br.readLine();

   while (line != null) {
     sb.append(line);
     line = br.readLine();

     if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
        Log.i("EMPTY LINE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",line);
     }

     if(line.equals(terminator)) {
        break;
     }
  }

// Create the final string
data = sb.toString();
}
```

Two issues. I would like to keep the empty lines in the received text. The terminator is not detected. I think, it is separated from the main text with two empty lines. However, after the first empty line, it goes to indefinite loop and connection never terminated.

EDIT #2.
After having spent several hours trying to figure out what is going on, making changes to the server, and comparing the number of bytes sent and received, I have noticed that this is not the problem with the code. It appears that the client receives the full text. The problem is with how the text is written in the console using the *Log.i(String, String)* method. I have added the good old `System.out.println()` in the code, and the whole text was shown in the console. However, the text from Log.i() was cut off in the middle. As this is my first experience with Android Studio, what the heck is going on?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())`. If you are not using `input` then why is it there?

Comment: You are reading byte for byte. Very inefficient. Especially while you also convert the sb to string for every char. Try to use br.readLine().

Comment: Let the server send "END_DATA\n" on a separate line. Then check the lines for this string. Not the whole sb.

Comment: "TCP client for Android: text is not sent in full". ? Not received fully?

Comment: The terminator is separated from the text by two empty lines. The readLine seems to work. Two issues. Empty lines in the text are removed. And the terminator is not detected. Looks like after the first empty line, I have an indefinite loop and the connection never stops.

Comment: You are getting an infinite loop because the `br.readLine();` is outside of the loop. hence you never read the second line.

Comment: That code was used in one of the examples. Replacing it with `String line = ""; while ( (line = br.readLine() ) != null) {} ` does not help.

Comment: `sb.append(line);` That should be `sb.append(line).append("\n");` to preserve the lines and empty lines. Put this statement after the readLine() statement.

Comment: `The terminator is separated from the text by two empty lines.` Ok. That does not matter. Be shure the server sends a \n after the terminator.

Comment: Hm. Looks more like a problem with `Log.i(String, String)` method than the TCP code. See my Edit #2. Great tips, anyways. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let talk about TCP socket first.

When talking about TCP socket, **it's a stream of data.**
TCP views data as an unstructured, **but ordered, stream of bytes**. It's different from the kinds of socket.io.

From time to time, TCP will grab chunks of data from the send buffer and pass the data to the network layer. The maximum amount of data that can be grabbed and placed in a segment is limited by the maximum segment size (MSS). The MSS is typically set by first determining the length of the largest link-layer frame.

So it depends on the device.

For example, you have two messages, each of them has 1000 bytes data, and you call:

-------------- client side ----------------

```
client.send(theFirstMessage) // 1000 bytes
client.send(theSecondMessage) // 1000 bytes
```

-------------- server side -----------------

```
socket.onReceived(data => {
    // process(data)
})
```

With above pseudocode you should note that:

The data which received and called on onReceived block couldn't be 1000 bytes of theFirstMessage.

1. It could be first 400 bytes, then on other event you receive 400 bytes, then more 400 bytes (200 of the first one and 200 of the second one).
2. It could be 1200 bytes (1000 of the first one and 200 of the second one).

TCP views data as an unstructured, **but ordered, stream of bytes**. Socket.io is a wrapper, when it uses TCP socket, it collect and combine/split the data for you, so that you received the events with exactly the data was sent from other side.
When you work with TCP, you have to do it your self, you have to define the application protocol to do it.

There're two common ways to send/receive TCP requests:

1. **Splitter**, you choose a splitter. For example, we choose 32 bits AABBCCDD as the splitter (same as you choose END_DATA string), but keep in mind it's binary data. Then you have to ensure that the data in request doesn't contains the **splitter**. To do that, you have to encode the request. For example we can encode request as base64, then use the character which isn't included in base64 table as the splitter.
2. **Prefix length**, the above method has its overhead as we have to encode request data. The prefix length method is a better choice.
   We can prefix the length of request before.

The pseudocode:

```
// use Int32, 4 bytes to indicate the length of message after it

-------------- client side ----------------
    client.send(theFirstMessage.length)    // Int32
    client.send(theFirstMessage) // 1000 bytes

    client.send(theSecondMessage.length) 
    client.send(theSecondMessage) // 1000 bytes


-------------- server side -----------------

    var buffer = Buffer()

    socket.onReceived(data => {
        buffer.append(data)

        let length = Int32(buffer[0...3])

        if (buffer.length >= length + 4) {
           let theRequest = buffer[4 ... 4 + length - 1]
           process(theRequest)

           buffer = buffer.dropFirst(4 + length)
        }

    })
```

One more thing, when working with TCP socket, it's just stream of bytes, so the endianness is important https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

For example, an android device is little endian and server side (or other android device) is big endian. Then 4 bytes of Int32 from the android device, when received on server side, it will be decoded wrongly if you don't care about it.

So, the prefix length should be encoded by specific endianness.